Creating patches from big TIFF file
I have a bit TIFF file with two bands. Most of it is NaN or zeros, and the only part I'm interested in is where there is information. So I'm trying to cut the image into patches of 64 by 64, and saving only the patches that are not FULL NaN/zeros, and also skipping the files that was already created.
I'm still getting patches full of NaN and this operation is taking too long..I have multiple files? How can improve the speed and make sure the algorithm does what I want?
Code below:
import os
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

# Input folder containing TIFF files
input_folder = 'path/to/input_folder'

# Output folder for the tiles
output_folder = 'path/to/output_folder'

# Tile size
tile_size = 64

# Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

# Iterate over all files in the input folder
for file in os.listdir(input_folder):
    # Check if the file is a TIFF file
    if file.endswith(".tif"):
        # Open the input TIFF file
        ds = gdal.Open(os.path.join(input_folder, file))

        # Get the width and height of the image
        width = ds.RasterXSize
        height = ds.RasterYSize

        # Calculate the number of rows and columns of tiles
        num_cols = width // tile_size
        num_rows = height // tile_size

        # Iterate over the rows and columns of tiles
        for i in range(num_rows):
            for j in range(num_cols):
                # Calculate the x and y offsets of the tile
                xoff = j * tile_size
                yoff = i * tile_size
                
                # Create the output file name
                output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{file}_row{i}_col{j}_tile.tif")
                
                # Skip if the output file already exists
                if os.path.exists(output_file):
                    continue
                
                # Use gdal_translate to crop the tile
                tile_ds = gdal.Translate(output_file, ds, srcWin=[xoff, yoff, tile_size, tile_size])
                
                # Read the tile data for all bands
                tile_data = [tile_ds.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray() for band in range(1, ds.RasterCount + 1)]
                
                # Check if all pixels are zeros or NaNs in all bands
                if all(np.all(np.isnan(band_data)) or np.all(band_data == 0) for band_data in tile_data):
                    # Remove the empty output file if all bands are zeros or NaNs
                    os.remove(output_file)
                    continue  # Skip saving the tile if all pixels are zeros or NaNs in all bands
                
                tile_ds = None  # Close the dataset
                
        # Get the last tile of all rows
        for i in range(num_rows):
            xoff = num_cols * tile_size
            yoff = i * tile_size
            output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{file}_row{i}_last_col.tif")
            remaining_width = width - (num_cols * tile_size)
            gdal.Translate(output_file, ds, srcWin=[xoff, yoff, remaining_width, tile_size])
            
        ds = None  # Close the dataset

print('Finished!')


How about running gdal2tiles.py then "gdalinfo -stats" on each of the resulting tiles.
https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html

probably won't work - sorry.

Use larger tiles, at least 256, or even 512 and try to align the TIFF blocks on these tiles. You can use gdal_translate to create a file with your desired block size. Or if you cannot adapt the TIFF, adapt the tiles.
